# StackGAN pickle error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get code from [this](https://github.com/hanzhanggit/StackGAN) repo running, which means I have to make this `get_data` function work:

```
def get_data(self, pickle_path, aug_flag=True):
    with open(pickle_path + self.image_filename, 'rb') as f:
        images = pickle.load(f)   # <--------- THIS line is the problem
        images = np.array(images)
        print('images: ', images.shape)
    # do more things here
```

But it gives me the error `ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3`
 so I found advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843698/valueerror-unsupported-pickle-protocol-3-python2-pickle-can-not-load-the-file), where they recommend a different protocol: `pickle.dump(images, f, protocol=2)`

```
def get_data(self, pickle_path, aug_flag=True):
    with open(pickle_path + self.image_filename, 'rb') as f:
        pickle.dump(images, f, protocol=2)   # still bad
        images = np.array(images)
        print('images: ', images.shape)
    # do more things here
```

However, that gives me the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'images' referenced before assignment`.  Is there a way I can fix this, specifically for `StackGAN/misc/datasets.py`?

Comment: just do `other_images =  np.array(images)`

Comment: The advice you're trying to follow is telling you how to change the code that *generates* the file in the first place, such that it creates a file that Pickle library implementations that only support protocol-2 can load. It's not telling you how to *load* a file created with the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571063/i-have-pickled-files-using-protocol-3-in-python3-and-now-i-need-to-unpickle-the?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
def get_data(self, pickle_path, aug_flag=True):
    with open(pickle_path + self.image_filename, 'rb') as f:
        pickle.dump(pickle.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout, 2)  # <----- *****
        images = np.array(images)
        print('images: ', images.shape)
    # do more things here
```

StackGAN supplies files pickled in Python3, and I needed to convert those to a Python2 protocol

Comment: Oops; this doesn't work.  Will look at the suggestions from comments in a bit